# Get reference from a textbox/item of a table on Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to do something that I do not know if is possible on Reporting Services that is create a kind of receipt.

I have already a table that breaks the page between every instance of a group and summarize the totals. Something like:

```
ID     -     Product  -     Invoice Number         -  Card Holder     -  Card Number  
01     -     Coffee   -     00121asdas-asd5458     -  James W L       -  xxxxx  xxxx xxx1235
02     -     Milk     -     154554bnvb-5sdfs57     -  James W L       -  xxxxx  xxxx xxx1235
```

I would to get some values/items from the same query used in that table and display them above the table where the headers will be located vertically. Eg:

```
   Card Holder: James W L 
   Card Number: xxxxx xxxx xxx1235
     Sale date: 2012-12-12
 Ticket number: 0000
----------------------------------------------
ID     -     Product  -     Invoice Number
01     -     Coffee   -     00121asdas-asd5458
02     -     Milk     -     154554bnvb-5sdfs57
```

How could I get those reference from that table to create a new table or expressions and be able to repeat than with the primary table in the next pages?

Please, give me a direction....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create static rows within the group, and show the `First` value of a certain column, scoped within the group. On those rows you will have to do some creative cell merging to get the layout you're suggesting.

Suppose you start with this for table layout:

```
+--------+------------+----------------------+----------------------+---------------+
| ID     |  Product   |     Invoice Number   | Card Holder          |  Card Number  |
+--------+------------+----------------------+----------------------+---------------+
| [id]   |  [Product] |     [InvoiceNr]      | [CardHolderName]     |  [CardNr]     |
+--------+------------+----------------------+----------------------+---------------+
```

You could create a few static rows in the group header, with merged cells:

```
+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|  Card Holder:       | =First(Fields!CardHolder.Value, "CardHolderGroup")          |
+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|  Card Number:       | =First(Fields!CardNr.Value, "CardHolderGroup")              |
+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|  Sale date:         | =First(Fields!SaleDate.Value, "CardHolderGroup")            |
+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|  Ticket number:     | =First(Fields!TicketNr.Value, "CardHolderGroup")            |
+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID     |  Product   |     Invoice Number   | Card Holder          |  Card Number  |
+--------+------------+----------------------+----------------------+---------------+
| [id]   |  [Product] |     [InvoiceNr]      | [CardHolderName]     |  [CardNr]     |
+--------+------------+----------------------+----------------------+---------------+
```

I'm not sure if I'm answering your question 100%, because I'm not entirely sure what you meant with the last bit on pages. Once you got your table structure I recommend looking through the MSDN pages on [repeating row group headers on pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207045.aspx).

Comment: many thanks @Jeroen... I creatd those static rows between the header and horizontal table (inside the group), then I moved the header to below the static rows to be on the correct place. The option "Advanced mode" of column groups also helped a lot to repeat it to each page.